# Pause and resume thread in java is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

I wanted to apply suspend/resume threads using wait()/notify() respectively.
I've tried repeatedly to solve this problem but I couldn't, so please kindly help me and explain why notify(); doesn't make counter thread runnable:

```
public class Suspend {
boolean isSuspend = false;
int counter = 0;

synchronized public void suspend() {    
    isSuspend = true;
    System.out.println("The counter was suspended!");
}

synchronized public void resume() {
    isSuspend = false;
    System.out.println("The counter was resumed :)");
    notify();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread.currentThread().setName("Main Thread");
    Suspend suspend = new Suspend();

    Thread counterThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        synchronized public void run() {
            while(!suspend.isSuspend) {
                System.out.println(suspend.counter++);
                try { Thread.sleep(1000); }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
            try {
                while(suspend.isSuspend)
                    wait();
                }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }, "Counter Thread");

    Thread suspendResumeThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        synchronized public void run() {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    suspend.suspend();
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    suspend.resume();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }
    }, "Suspend/Resume Thread");

    counterThread.start();
    suspendResumeThread.start();
}
```

}

The output is as following:

`0
1
2
3
4
The counter was suspended!
The counter was resumed :)
The counter was suspended!
The counter was resumed :)
... and so on.`

Comment: `boolean isSuspend = false;` should probably be volatile or use an `AtomicBoolean` instead

Comment: Your first thread waits one second so it prints 5 times  before the second one suspend the "lock" so the first thread loop breaks. Since you simply calling wait() after a notify() the code will be resumed, but has no code to execute after, the correct is to call wait() inside the while loop and change it to while(true) with some break condition inside.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for your comment, I tried both volatile and AtomicBoolean, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos Thank you for your comment, I tried the following but it doesn't work:
while(true) {
 try {
        if(!suspend.isSuspend) {
   System.out.println(suspend.counter++);
   try { Thread.sleep(1000); }
   catch (InterruptedException e) {}
  }
  else
   wait();
 }
 catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are those lines:

```
while (suspend.isSuspend)
    wait();
}
```

in your `counterThread` Runnable.

**You wait on the `Runnable`, not on the `suspend` object**

You need to synchronize on `suspend` and call wait() on `suspend`:

```
synchronized (suspend) {
    while (suspend.isSuspend)
        suspend.wait();
    }
}
```

Also, your `run` methods don't need to be synchronized.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Johannes Kuhn, really your code is 100% correct.

Comment: The `while` loop **must be inside the synchronized block** or this is not thread safe.  The whole point of `wait()` is that it’s an atomic operation, but only while the lock is held.

Comment: Actually, if `suspend.isSuspended` is `volatile`, then it doesn't need to be synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to counterThread while, it end at first change of isSuspend flag.

I think you need something like this:

```
public class Suspend {
volatile boolean isSuspend = false;
int counter = 0;

synchronized public void suspend() {    
    isSuspend = true;
    System.out.println("The counter was suspended!");
}

synchronized public void resume() {
    isSuspend = false;
    System.out.println("The counter was resumed :)");
    notify();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread.currentThread().setName("Main Thread");
    Suspend suspend = new Suspend();

    Thread counterThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        synchronized public void run() {
            while(true){
                while(!suspend.isSuspend) {
                    System.out.println(suspend.counter++);
                    try { Thread.sleep(1000); }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                }
                try {
                    while(suspend.isSuspend)
                        wait();
                }catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                }
             }
         }
    }, "Counter Thread");

    Thread suspendResumeThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        synchronized public void run() {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    suspend.suspend();
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    suspend.resume();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }
    }, "Suspend/Resume Thread");

    counterThread.start();
    suspendResumeThread.start();
}
```

In the end you need to use `volatile` keyword too on shared variables

EDIT: i've pasted the wrong code sorry

Comment: Thank you for this important note: ** you need to use volatile keyword too on shared variables**. But your code it doesn't work and the counter thread it didn't end. According to the debugger, the status of counterThread is "waiting for: Suspend$1  (id=19)"

Comment: True, I didn't noticed the missing syncronized on suspend object, but anyway you need the extra while (true)